# Issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Well I started to integrate the firbase cloud messaging for iOS. I read this article to implement FCM.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

I have been following this doc to implement FCM but somehow I am not able to access few methods & classes instance.

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self //No such class Messaging
```

Could find the method in protocol as mentioned below

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
  print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

  // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
  // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

So please tell what here am I doing wrong.

Comment: did you included pod 'Firebase/Messaging' ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This.For Swift**

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// START refresh_token
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    print("Received Remote Message: 1\nCheck Out:\n")

}
// END refresh_token
// START ios 10 data message
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    print("Received Remote Message: 2\nCheck Out:\n")
}




// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received Remote Message: 3\nCheck In:\n")
    debugPrint(remoteMessage.appData)
    print("Received Remote Message: 3\nCheck Out:\n")

 }
   // END ios 10 data message
}
```